# Entity Framework 4 cast object to dynamic proxy

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco, dynamic-proxy

In EF4, is it possible to convert a POCO object (created using new MyObject()) to a Dynamic Proxy (like you would get with ObjectContext.CreateObject())?

Using EF4 with T4 template for POCO.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. It is a reason why CreateObject method exists.